# Kernel module not getting installed after upgrade

Tags: drivers, kernel

I just upgraded from 20.04 and things seem to be in order except the generic VM audio snd_hda_intel.

I keep getting the error:

```
modprobe snd-hda-intel
# modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-hda-intel not found in directory /lib/modules/5.[*]-generic
```

I thought maybe the new kernel (5.15..23) was missing the module, so I've tried 4 other kernels, plus generic and my lowlatency - 5.4, 5.13, 5.14, 5.17. The first didnt boot, but the others had the same error. It must be a configuration problem. The only possible clue I have is when trying to reinstall my old working kernel (5.4.0-105-lowlatency), it said [residual config]. I tried some suggestions to change the conf file, but the module is actually not where its looking for it, and not at all in the ../sound dir "/lib/modules/5.17.0-051700rc7-generic/kernel/sound/".. there is no "pci" dir at all. So its not being installed, even though I assume it would have been in at least on of the versions I tried.

Also `dpkg -S snd-hda-intel` says it finds the module in all the kernels. It must be searching either the package listing or the deb file contents, because its not on disk.

```
linux-modules-5.17.0-051700rc7-generic: /lib/modules/5.17.0-051700rc7-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko
linux-modules-5.4.5-050405-lowlatency: /lib/modules/5.4.5-050405-lowlatency/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko
...
```

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc. *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*   Also don't forget it's still in *alpha* with *beta* freeze just *hit* & *beta* release on 31-March-2022

Comment: Loading that module worked fine for me on my test Ubuntu desktop 22.04 VM.

Comment: Thanks all.. I used `do-release-upgrade -d`. I dont think its a 'its not ready' issue. As Doug says, it works on his 22.04. It's some configuration problem, as even the old kernels *before 22.04* dont work.

Comment: @DougSmythies thank you for that info! Could you `modprobe snd_hda_intel` and tell me the location maybe? I'd like to see if there is a new location, or the one it is reporting is correct, which matches the kernel contents list.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2473356&p=14088567#post14088567

Answer (score 1):

I made some progress with `apt install --reinstall linux-modules-5.15.0-23-generic && apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-23-generic`. I'm pretty sure I tried that. Yes, it doesnt hold after reboot. So maybe.. idk..

I did also try removing the [residual-config] marked old packages with this `apt-get remove --purge $(dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}')` but I may have been just rebooting after reinstalling the kernel modules and extras without doing `modprobe snd-hda-intel` which loads the module and now the sound is working.

Hmm, what would be causing the modules to go missing after reboot. maybe a blacklist?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405146/removed-lib-modules-folder-after-every-reboot

The fix turned out to be adding `snd_hda_intel` to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules. I'll file a bug report.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1967593

Actually, I think it was the removal of this `apt-get remove cloud-initramfs-copymods` package that mounts on top of modules. My image was built on top of a cloud-init server image, so that could explain why a commentor said his sound worked.

---

Testing on a new copy of the images showed it was the cloud-initramfs-copymods package (likely has nothing to do with 22.04), that just needs to be removed, restarted once, and then the kernel modules file reinstalled, and `modprobe snd_hda_intel`. (the modules-extras reinstall wasnt necessary with lowlatency version). `ufw` now works too.

Comment: I'd have suggested you would have been better posting that detail on UF rather than here.. You've already got a number of *off-topic hits* against this post, which SE remembers.... even after posts get closed as off-topic & deleted.  On UF you're on-topic, and that site is monitored for issues with *jammy* unlike this site (*even if you end up being requested to file a bug report as occurs here with development questions*).

Comment: @guiverc in 13 days your point is moot. I almost have it fixed. And this info will help others. So please dont remove. That seems like ridiculously pedantic and not practical.

Comment: @guiverc SE sites are much easier to edit, post, and get the best answer than any forum.

Comment: You can see this is a general issue with Ubuntu from the Unix SE reference.

Comment: FYI:  Release date is scheduled for 21-March-2022  (*that's more than 13 days if you check a calendar*), you can check my first comment for the link to the official schedule for *jammy*